# Does a lightsaber that opens up in the middle exist?

Tags: star-wars

Assuming the split hilt was made of beskar or something similar, could the two hilts be held only by the blade of the lightsaber?

I've created an an image to show what I mean.

[image: "Reverse lightsaber?"]

Does this exist?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  _Can_ it be done?  That's up to Disney's writers.  (So likely to be closed as future works or opinion-based.)  _Has_ something like that ever been done?  That might be a question you could ask.  Please try to write questions that have definitive answers that can be supported by canonical information.  You might want to take the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

In a word, maybe. We do actually have a pretty comparable weapon that exists in the Legends canon which is [Lumiya's lightwhip](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lumiya%27s_lightwhip). It consists of a cortosis handle, flexible emitters along a series of linked metal components and metallic flail tips that contain electro-shocking components.

[image]

Assuming we replaced the flail tips with another metal handle, you'd basically have what you've described; a split-handle lightsaber with a (flexible) lightsaber cutting blade running between them.